# Callbacks and this

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a directory with files that I need to parse and save in an array of JavaScript objects.  In the constructor, as soon as I reach **point 2** in the code below, `this` becomes `undefined` and in **point 3** I don't have access to `this.data`. What's the best way to fix the code and achieve the goal?

```
function Service(path) {
    this.data = [];
    console.log(this); // point 1
    fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
        console.log(this); // point 2
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            fs.readFile(path + file, function (err, data) {
                parseString(data, function (err, result) {
                    this.data.push(result); // point 3
                });
            });
        }, this);
    });
}

Service.prototype.getData = function () {
   // do something with `this.data` and return the result
};
```

I tried saving `this` as `self`, but in the end `self` ends up with proper array, while `this` does not:

```
  function Service(path) {
    var self = this;
    this.data = [];
    fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            fs.readFile(path + file, function (err, data) {
                parseString(data, function (err, result) {
                    self.data.push(result);
                });
            });
        });
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(this); \\ point x
        console.log(self); \\ point y
    }, 3000);    
  }

  Service.prototype.getData = function () {
    // do something with `this.data` and return the result
  };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Keep in mind, this example isn't very safe. You have an asynchronous constructor, but no callback or loaded method to use which will let you know when the data is ready. You can't just use: var service = new Service(path); service.getData();`.

Comment: Yes, so what would be the best way to do it?  Promises?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` object changes anytime you change from a function's scope to another.

You can solve this by saving the `this` object you want to a variable (in my example: `self`):

```
function Service(path) {
    var self = this;
    self.data = [];
    console.log(this); // point 1
    fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
        console.log(self); // point 2
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            fs.readFile(path + file, function (err, data) {
                parseString(data, function (err, result) {
                    self.data.push(result); // point 3
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

Service.prototype.getData = function () {
    var self = this;

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(self.data);
    }, 100);
};

var serv = new Service();
serv.getData(); // your array
```

See [documentation on Mozilla for `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

To see an example, please refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgv18opp/).

Comment: Please see my 2nd example, using `self` instead of `this`. In that example `self` ends up with proper array but `this` does not.

Comment: use `this` to assign it to another variable. After that, dont use it anymore. As I said, `this` may change anytime your scope change.

Comment: In this case, How do I refer do `data` from `Service.prototype.getData = function() {...}` function?

Comment: Use it like in the example above. Then you can call `new Service(path).data` and it should work fine.

Comment: Put the entire prototype code in the OP if your issue includes those prototypes.

Comment: @Makaze I need to access it from inside the object.  See my comment above.

Comment: `var self = this;`, then use `self` instead of `this` anywhere inside your function, even if it comes from a prototype assignment.

Comment: @lante But how do I access `data` from another function of the same object in this case?  `self` is not available in function prototypes of the object.

Comment: you just assigned `data` to `this`, so just do `this.data`, (or `self.data`, after assigning `this` to `self`) from the other function.

Comment: @lante Please see my code again  In `point y`, I have proper array in `self`, but in `point x` `this` still has an empty array.  So yes, I can access `this.data` from a function prototype, BUT it doesn't has empty array, not the actual data.  I don't see why.

Comment: I think it's because this.data has to be redefined. Posting working example as answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgv18opp/). It may help.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Vsevolod's answer, you can also use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
function Service(path) {
    this.data = [];
    console.log(this); // point 1
    fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
        console.log(this); // point 2
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            fs.readFile(path + file, function (err, data) {
                parseString(data, function (err, result) {
                    this.data.push(result); // point 3
                }.bind(this));
            });
        }, this);
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Bind is slower than using a closure, but that only really matters in very tight loops where you're doing a ton of iterations and is unlikely to be an issue in most scenarios.

Comment: Yep, this is valid, but imo the code becomes more error-prone with multiple callbacks then just using `var self = this`

Answer (score 1):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) refers to the 'current' context.

In you example you can just save the 'outer' `this` to a local variable

```
function Service(path) {
    var $this = this;
    this.data = [];
    console.log(this); // point 1
    fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {
        console.log($this); // point 2
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            fs.readFile(path + file, function (err, data) {
                parseString(data, function (err, result) {
                    $this.data.push(result); // point 3
                });
            });
        }, $this);
    });
}
```

PS while using `bind` is not prohibited either, the solution with assigning `this` to a local variable looks more elegant and will ensure that you will not forget to add another `bind` to the callback

Comment: Please see my 2nd example.  Using this example `self` ends up with proper array but `this` does not.

Comment: `this` will not work as it refers to the current context, which changes when you are in another function. Check the MDN article I've referenced

Comment: Fixed that, might have overlooked it

Comment: Right.  But how do I access `data` from another function of the same object in this case?

Comment: Yes, you are accessing the `data` of your 'outside' function inside of the callback

Comment: I mean I cannot access `data` from function prototype of this object

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is the case, but if you do `this.data = this.data` or `self = this`  in your prototype it outputs the correct value. Otherwise it returns the whole Service instance at the time it was created. Here is a snippet you can try with a dummy `Service` and `getData` example.

```js
function Service(array) {
  var self = this;
  this.data = [];
  console.log(this); // point 1
  array.forEach(function(item) {
    self.data.push(item); // point 2
  });
}

Service.prototype.getData = function() {
  self = this;
  return self.data;
};

var serv = new Service(['bob', 'aerith']);

console.log(serv.getData());
```